# is it possible to target an image only with his src link with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, image

I would like to hide / show text when clicking on images, knowing that the class images id are all the same, and I can't change this.
So I tried below to target the images by their link src.
But it doesn't work : only one of the three text appear, and he didn't disappear when clinking on the other image.

Any ideas please ?

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cyan").hide();
  $("#red").hide();

$('img').on({
    'click': function() {
     $(this).attr('src') === 'cyan-color.gif'
  $("#cyan").show();
  $("#red").hide();
    }
});
$('img').on({
    'click': function() {
     $(this).attr('src') === 'red-color.gif'
  $("#red").show();
  $("#cyan").hide();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="cyan">cyan</div>
<div id="red">red</div>
<img class="same_class" src="cyan-color.gif" />
<img class="same_class" src="red-color.gif" />
```

Comment: The contents of your click handlers are malformed.  There is no conditional paired with an true and false block.  You have one statement performing a conditional, followed by two statements, which are not controlled at all by the results of the conditional

Comment: `if ($(this).attr('src') === 'whatever') { ...true case... } else { ...false case... }`

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you're looking for, you only need one click handler the way you set it up:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cyan").hide();
  $("#red").hide();

  $('img').on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).attr('src') === 'cyan-color.gif') {
        $("#cyan").show();
        $("#red").hide();
      }
      if ($(this).attr('src') === 'red-color.gif') {
        $("#red").show();
        $("#cyan").hide();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cyan">cyan</div>
<div id="red">red</div>
<img class="same_class" src="cyan-color.gif" />
<img class="same_class" src="red-color.gif" />
```

Here's a JSFiddle of the same thing:  https://jsfiddle.net/y67jd3b0/

I also corrected a couple of small syntax errors (no colon in the on click method, incorrect closing brackets) and made it a bit more readable.